# Italicise text in latex figure caption produced by knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to to italicise some text in a figure caption created by knitr. I have the code below in a .Rnw file and I'm converting it to a .tex file using knitr:

```
<<plot_setosa, fig.cap="A plot of $\\textit{setosa}$">>=

plot(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",])

@
```

How can I italicise setosa in the figure caption?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
<<plot_setosa, fig.cap="A plot of \\textit{setosa}">>=

plot(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",])

@
```

No need for the `$$`