# reference a previously defined object in a `knitr` Rnw chunk figure caption

Tags: r, knitr

Is it possible to reference a previously defined object in a `knitr` Rnw chunk figure caption?

```
<<chunk1>>=
  myObj <- "caption"
@

<<chunk2, fig.cap="This is my \\Sexpr{myObj}">>=
  plot(1,2)
@
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956049/italicise-text-in-latex-figure-caption-produced-by-knitr) shows how to use LaTeX in a figure caption, but I can't get the same idea to work with `\Sexpr{}` and an R object.

Comment: Does `fig.cap=paste("This is my", myObj)` work?

Comment: yes, @MrFlick. good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MrFlick offered a simple solution:

```
fig.cap=paste("This is my", myObj)
```

Documenting here to close the question.